# MySql SELECT Subqueries JOIN

Tags: mysql, select, join, subquery

I am trying to do all of these `SELECT` statements in all one query so I will be able to further it and group it.  I believe I have to tell it to `JOIN` on TABLE1.  I can tell you that it should be JOINing on the field called `ITEM`.  I have tried dozens of JOIN statements none of which does the trick because I have two `WHERE` statements in my subqueries.

```
SELECT ITEM, DSI, LEADTIME,
(SELECT COUNT(ORDER_NUMBER) FROM SUBTABLE1 TR1 WHERE TRANS_DATE BETWEEN DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 730 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 365 DAY))
as OLDORDERS,
(SELECT COUNT(ORDER_NUMBER) FROM SUBTABLE2 TR2 WHERE TRANS_DATE BETWEEN DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 364 DAY) AND curdate())
as NEWORDERS
FROM TABLE1
```

Displays:

```
ITEM   |  DSI  |  LEADTIME  | OLDORDERS | NEWORDERS
PROD-1    0         1          16036      38399
PROD-2    1         0          16036      38399
PROD-3    1         1          16036      38399
```

Again...I believe I need it to `JOIN` the field `ITEM` on the subqueries, but I do not know how to do this, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't actually need a `JOIN`, *per se*; rather, you need to "correlate" your subqueries, so that they refer to data in their containing query.

You haven't given your exact table definitions, so I can't say for sure, but here's my guess at what you need:

```
SELECT item, dsi, leadtime,
       ( SELECT COUNT(order_number)
           FROM subtable1
          WHERE trans_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 730 DAY)
                               AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 365 DAY)
                -- restrict to "current" record from TABLE1:
            AND subtable1.item = table1.item
       ) as OLDORDERS,
       ( SELECT COUNT(order_number)
           FROM subtable1
          WHERE trans_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 364 DAY)
                               AND CURDATE()
                -- restrict to "current" record from table1:
            AND subtable1.item = table1.item
       ) as NEWORDERS
  FROM table1
;
```

That's assuming that `table1.item` is the primary key, and that `subtable1.item` is a foreign-key referring to it. Naturally you'll have to adjust the query if that's not the case.

Comment: I do believe this works, I have to set a `LIMIT` on it to work otherwise it timesout.